# Run As administrator for .exe file from Azure Pipeline and powershell script

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I  am struggling with one `.exe` file. I want to start the .exe file using power shell for that I have a command like below 
`Start-Process "F:\Home\mydotteller.exe" -Verb runAs` .
and the wondering thing is if I ran the above command from servers am able to start the .exe file with administrator privilege and am getting expected output.
But if I tried from azure Pipeline or a .ps1 script it's not working as expected. 
and servers are enabled with UAC. can someone help me to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using hosted agents, or do you have self-hosted agents? Because on hosted agents, this will _not_ fly. Those run in a sandbox, where you cannot get administrative access.

Comment: @rickvdbosch   using powershell task as deployment group job, and there i have pasted command to start process.

Comment: Again: are you using (Microsoft) hosted agents or are you hosting build agents yourself?

Comment: @rickvdbosch second option ..self hosted.

Comment: If you use your self hosted agent, then when installing the build agent what account did you choose? As long as the agent runs as Windows service and that account is in local administrators group, your script should run as expected.

Comment: no worries @LexLi we are using services accounts which have all admin access.

Comment: @Prasanth K S Could you please explain "it's not working as expected" specifically? and is there any error message when you run the pipeline?

Comment: @LeviLu-MSFT ,  thats interesting thing from log its seems .exe file got started , but when i check the server task manager there will not be action. this is my actual prblm,.

Comment: As @LexLi pointed out: if you install a self-hosted agent to run as a service under an account that has administrator access, your application should run as expected. What is the functionality of the executable? Is the executable yours? And if so: could you add some logging?

Answer (score 0):

We made [AzureAdmin](https://github.com/sofdigital/AzureAdmin) exactly for this. We were having problems removing Appx packages in our self hosted build before UI testing and the Powershell task isn't evevated even though its run by an admin account via the agent. We built a lightweight .Netcore Worker service with http request capability. As long as you install the service with admin privileges, You can send a Invoke-RestMethod command from a regular Powershell YML task and it will trigger your custom logic on the other end of the ASP controller that needs elevated privileges. The example controller on the project already implements Powershell commands to work off of.